# Someone goes question after question of mine and downvotes, what can be done?

Tags: discussion

Someone goes question after question of mine and downvotes, what can be done?

This manner is extremely unlikely to be natural; It all happened in 10 minutes. What can be done against that?

Comment: Sounds a lot like [serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me); if it is, it'll be reversed.

Comment: And if the user is very experienced in the mechanics of the SE system and can deceive these? It might be the case, this is not the first time it happens with the user I think it is.

Comment: Focus on asking better questions; that *is* within your control. Imaginary vendettas are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only quote the FAQ page I linked to in the comments:

---

### What if I think I'm the victim of voting fraud?

If the voting fraud is in the progress of happening or just happened recently, don't worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing before becoming concerned. The system should detect it and reverse it for you. Please **do not** try to get help on this issue on meta or by flagging for a moderator. All they will do is tell you to wait for the voting fraud script to run (they can't run it for you just this once).

If the 24 hours has already passed and the suspicious votes have not been reversed, you can then flag one of your own posts and explain what happened so a moderator can look into it. It is generally preferred that you *avoid* asking about them on a site's meta, since details of the investigation cannot be divulged and you won't actually get any information that will be useful to other members of the community.

**See also:** [What should you do if you're serial downvoted & it isn't automatically reversed within 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-its-not-automatically-reversed/212339)

Answer (score 2):

You should note that several of your posts have multiple down votes. 
For example, [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421633/23408) has six. 
That means that at least six different users are down voting your posts.

Also, in a quick scan of [your reputation history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/273994/user9303970?tab=reputation&sort=post),
I don’t see any clusters of many down votes in a ten-minute period. 
Have they been removed?

Comment: No, well I had 2 clashes with 2 users, very experienced with the system that I won't mention their names here, They made some of these, I'm sure.

Comment: Despite being sure, you're most likely wrong.